# C++ compile in Arch Linux with no g++ package in repositories

Tags: arch-linux, gcc, c++

I want to compile a C++ program in Arch Linux, but there's no "g++" package as there is in Ubuntu repositories for example.

Using `-x` too won't work. like this:

```
gcc -x c++ -o myprog myprog.cpp
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

gcc is both a C and C++ compiler.
It will look at the file's extension and process accordingly.
g++ is only a wrapper that calls gcc
g++ is installed with the gcc package in Arch

```
gcc file.C # uppercase .C (or .cpp) will process as C++ 
gcc file.c # lowercase .c will process as C
```

Comment: Though I have gcc on my Arch, there's no g++, and though my file is `prog.cpp` and I also use `-x c++` I should tell you it only works in case I also add `-lstdc++`, which correctly compiles. Do you suggest this method? (`gcc -x c++ -o myprog -lstdc++ myprog.cpp`)

Comment: if you use std c++  in your code then yes, you need to link (-lstdc++) with the std c++ library.
I've installed gcc on my arch and g++ is present. It should be in /usr/bin, I don't believe the -x c++ is needed if file extension is .cpp, gcc should select on that

Comment: g++ should be part of the gcc package.  Have you tried reinstalling gcc?

Comment: g++ is part of the gcc package

Comment: You gotta be right Craig. I had not installed the gcc manually, since I thought having access to gcc should mean that I've got the whole package on system, but pacman shows me there's 18MB to download for the gcc package. I haven't done it yet but I'm sure it works as soon as I do it. Thanks for your helps, Craig and bdowning.